# Correct way of implementing article and it's comments in react env

Tags: reactjs, redux, fetch

I'm implemeting article view in react with user comments in it. I'm wondering if should I use redux and actions such as: FETCH_COMMENTS, EDIT_COMMENT and reducers for updating state (adding signle comment to the initial state fetched from wepabi and  changing signle comment searched by ID) or just simple use of fetch (post) in class component (without redux) for adding comment and then just fetch again to get new array of comments from api - in this case im gonna re-render all comments instead of one but user gonna have new comments after adding his own, right?

What's the best solution for that situation?? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I struggle to edit comment, here is what you could do:

After POST comment to DB, I would fetch GET request to refresh the data, and send the GET request to action.

**Action** (this is the simpliest example, you can then handle loading and errors):

```
export const ActionGetAllComments = payload => ({
  type: GET_ALL_COMMENTS,
  payload
});



export const ActionPostComment = (URL_API_POST_COMMENT, URL_API_GET_COMMENTS) => {

  return dispatch => {
    axios.post(URL_API_POST_COMMENTS)
    .then(()=>axios.get(URL_API_GET_COMMENT))
    .then((response)=>response.data)
    .then(response => dispatch(ActionGetAllComments(response))  
  }
};
```

As you would get all comments in the GET request, the reducer would simply return all the results without concatenation needed as it would overwrite the previous state.
**Reducer**:

```
export const ReducerGetAllComments = (state=[], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
        case GET_ALL_COMMENTS:
                return action.payload
        default:
                return state;
  }
};
```

You need to add redux-thunk to your package and to setup in your store like this:

```
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'  

    export const Store = createStore(
      rootReducer,
      applyMiddleware(thunk)
    )
```

If you need to target specific comments depending on user ID, you can add the ID argument in ActionPostComment. Then send it to your requests, build the queries in the back-end route, and send back the final result via GET request.

Comment: Thanks, ill do this way i guess ;)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you axios (to check fetch errors easily) combined with an async request via redux thunk to be sure your data will be shown up.

Redux thunk is quite easy, it is for including the request in the action, and dispatch data in other actions. Typical other actions are 'loading' and 'error', but you can skip them if you wish.
Here is an example of one of my project:

```
export const ActionGetGroupListLoading = bool => ({
  type: GET_GROUP_LIST_LOADING,
  isLoading: bool
});

export const ActionGetGroupListSuccess = groupList => ({
  type: GET_GROUP_LIST_SUCCESS,
  groupList
});

export const ActionGetGroupListError = bool => ({
  type: GET_GROUP_LIST_ERROR,
  hasErrored: bool
});


export const ActionGetGroupList = url => {

  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(ActionGetGroupListLoading(true));
    axios.get(url)
      .then(response => response.data)
      .then(grouplist => dispatch(ActionGetGroupListLoading(false)) && dispatch(ActionGetGroupListSuccess(grouplist)))
      .catch(() => dispatch(ActionGetGroupListError(true)));
  }
};
```

You can add several requests in action ActionGetGroupList and cross data inside like this example:

```
export const ActionGetUserInfo = payload => ({
  type: GET_USER_INFO,
  payload
});

export const ActionLoadingUserInfo = bool => ({
  type: 'LOADING',
  isLoading: bool
});

export const ActionGetUserInfoAsync = (url, groupId, userId) => {

  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(ActionLoadingUserInfo(true));
    axios.post(url, {   
      groupId,
      userId,
    })
    .then(()=>fetch(`http://localhost/api/getuser/${userId}`))
    .then((response)=>response.json())
    .then(response => dispatch(ActionLoadingUserInfo(false)) && dispatch(ActionGetUserInfo(response)))
  }
};
```

Comment: Ok, but how about server response in that case? After adding comment, server should response with simple 'success' message or should contain added comment object to handle it in recuder to update state? Example server response: `newComment = {id: 2, user: [...], content: 'comment about something imporatnt'}` then I could do something like this in reducer `return [...state, newComment]`

Comment: After POST comment to DB, I would fetch GET request to refresh the data.